# Is it Possible XSS in <h1> tags without using "<"

Tags: web-application, xss

In example website "<" character is filtered.Is it possible to find XSS in h1 XSS h1

Comment: Depends on how it is filtered and the injection context. You need to give more detail for us to help you out.

Comment: @zyk xss should be between h1 tags and "<tag" filtered. but "< tag" is working

Comment: Browser will not render the HTML code if there is a space between the first anchor tag and the first keyword. However, there are a lot of other techniques and it really depends on the scenario. Double-encoded string might be one of the way to bypass the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

When in a basic HTML context, you need `<[a-zA-Z]` to gain XSS in modern browsers. See for example portswiggers [unexploitable XSS](https://portswigger.net/research/documenting-the-impossible-unexploitable-xss-labs).

<sub>This is of course assuming that the filter is working correctly and can't be bypassed.</sub>